# How to decode JWT Token?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, jwt, visual-studio-2022

I don't understand how this library works. Could you help me please ?

Here is my simple code :

```
public void TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler()
    {
        var stream =
            "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJJU1MiLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbGFyaW0uZG5zY2UuZG91YW5lL2NpZWxzZXJ2aWNlL3dzIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kb3VhbmUuZmluYW5jZXMuZ291di5mci9vYXV0aDIvdjEiLCJpYXQiOiJcL0RhdGUoMTQ2ODM2MjU5Mzc4NClcLyJ9";
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
    }
```

This is the error :

> The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form: Base64UrlEncodedHeader.Base64UrlEndcodedPayload.OPTIONAL,Base64UrlEncodedSignature'.

If you copy the stream in [jwt.io website](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io), it works fine :)

Comment: the jwt,io site decodes it, but there is no signature so it is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding and verifying JWT token using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677837/decoding-and-verifying-jwt-token-using-system-identitymodel-tokens-jwt)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim you're right it's duplicate question ... but answers are different because of version library you use

Comment: You better do not share tokens on public webs, because we can get information that maybe is not secure but sencible

Answer (score 373, accepted):

I found the solution, I just forgot to Cast the result:

```
var stream = "[encoded jwt]";  
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
var tokenS = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
```

Or, without the cast:

```
var token = "[encoded jwt]";  
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
```

I can get Claims using:

```
var jti = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "jti").Value;
```

Comment: I had to cast tokenS.Claims as a List of Claims first. `((List<Claim>)tokenS.Claims).ForEach(a => 
                Console.WriteLine(a.Type.ToString() + " " + a.Value));`

Comment: For Registered Claims you can get the property value directly off of the `JwtSecurityToken`. For example, `tokenS.Id` will get you the jti value

Comment: You can also do: handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenJwtReponse.access_token);

Comment: Also, don't use type-safe casting unless you are expecting it to NOT be of that type. Use `(JwtSecurityToken)handler.ReadToken(tokenJwtReponse.access_token)` so that you get `InvalidCastException` instead of some later `NullReferenceException`. See [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/)

Comment: Sorry if this should be obvious but where is `tokenJwtReponse.access_token` coming from?

Comment: Where is tokenJwtReponse.access_token coming from?

Comment: As others have already questioned: where does "tokenJwtReponse.access_token" come from?  There is no definition or declaration for it in the answer, making the answer useless and meaningless for many of us.

Comment: I'm assuming `tokenJwtResponse` is a deserialized json response containing a key `access_token` with the actual JWT token.

Comment: replace tokenJwtReponse.access_token in the above with stream

Comment: Your examples should be self contained and testable. This doesn't build.

Comment: I needed to include the following NuGet package to use it within my Azure Function: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Comment: the tokenJwtReponse.access_token is simply the string of the access token (without "Bearer " in the start)

Comment: There are probably other ways to get the access token in other scenarios, but from within a Controller, I can get it using ---> var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

Answer (score 60):

`new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken("")` will return a `SecurityToken`

`new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken("")` will return a `JwtSecurityToken`

If you just change the method you are using you can avoid the cast in the above answer

Comment: What is the namespace / package?

Comment: @justin.m.chase  `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Answer (score 39):

You need the secret string which was used to generate encrypt token. 
This code works for me:

```
protected string GetName(string token)
    {
        string secret = "this is a string used for encrypt and decrypt token"; 
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
        var claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validations, out var tokenSecure);
        return claims.Identity.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `handler.ReadToken(token) as SecurityToken` when you're reassigning it as your `out` parameter later? Is there a possibility that `ValidateToken` fails and the original value is kept?

Comment: Right krillgar is not nesessary the cast to SecurityToken

Comment: Does ValidateToken check the expiration? Or do I need to validate that myself after it is decoded?

Comment: @computrius ValidateToken takes a `TokenValidationParameters`, which is constructed on the line before the call, as clearly seen in the answer. This object will tell the validator what to check for.

Answer (score 27):

```
  var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
  var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
  var claims = new[]
  {
      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, model.UserName),
      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, model.Id.ToString()),
  };
  var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
      _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
      claims,
      expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
      signingCredentials: creds);
```

Then extract content

```
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
 string authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
 authHeader = authHeader.Replace("Bearer ", "");
 var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(authHeader);
 var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(authHeader) as JwtSecurityToken;
 var id = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "nameid").Value;
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I've been searching for ages, and yours was the first answer that made sense and worked!

Comment: By the way, you can change `"Authorization"` to `Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Authorization` if you don't like hard-coded strings

Answer (score 19):

Using .net core jwt packages, the Claims are available:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy = "Bearer")]
public class AbstractController: ControllerBase
{
    protected string UserId()
    {
        var principal = HttpContext.User;
        if (principal?.Claims != null)
        {
            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
               log.Debug($"CLAIM TYPE: {claim.Type}; CLAIM VALUE: {claim.Value}");
            }

        }
        return principal?.Claims?.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Type == "username")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only feasible when using ASP.NET Core based middleware pipeline, OP asked specifically for the handler's implementation inside implementation `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` which suits a broader set of use cases.

Answer (score 16):

I write this solution and it's work for me

```
    protected Dictionary<string, string> GetTokenInfo(string token)
    {
        var TokenInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        var claims = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.ToList();

        foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            TokenInfo.Add(claim.Type, claim.Value);
        }

        return TokenInfo;
    }
```

Comment: var claims = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.ToList();  ----->

var claims = jwtSecurityToken.Claims;

Comment: This is the best and simple answer, totally working! Should have been the selected answer

Comment: Shorter way to do it is:

`Dictionary<string, string> dicClaims = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Value);`

Answer (score 5):

Though this answer is not answering the original question but its a really very useful feature for C# developers, so adding it as the answer.

Visual Studio 2022 has added a feature to decode the value of a token at runtime.

You can check the feature in Visual Studio 2022 preview (version 17.5.0 preview 2.0)

Mouse over the variable containing the JWT and then select the string manipulation as JWT Decode, and you can see the token value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Extending on [cooxkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610077/cooxkie) answer, and [dpix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097585/dpix) answer, when you are reading a jwt token (such as an access_token received from AD FS), you can merge the claims in the jwt token  with the claims from "context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity" that might not have the same set of claims as the jwt token.

To Illustrate, in an Authentication Code flow using OpenID Connect,after a user is authenticated, you can handle the event [SecurityTokenValidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt180993%28v%3dvs.113%29) which provides you with an authentication context, then you can use it to read the access_token as a jwt token, then you can "merge" tokens that are in the access_token with the standard list of claims received as part of the user identity:

```
    private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage,OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        //get the current user identity
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

        /*read access token from the current context*/
        string access_token = context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler hand = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        //read the token as recommended by Coxkie and dpix
        var tokenS = hand.ReadJwtToken(access_token);
        //here, you read the claims from the access token which might have 
        //additional claims needed by your application
        foreach (var claim in tokenS.Claims)
        {
            if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(claim.Type, claim.Value))
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
    public static string Get_Payload_JWTToken(string token)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var DecodedJWT = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        string payload = DecodedJWT.EncodedPayload;  // Gives Payload
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FromBase64Url(payload));
    }
    static byte[] FromBase64Url(string base64Url)
    {
        string padded = base64Url.Length % 4 == 0
        ? base64Url : base64Url + "====".Substring(base64Url.Length % 4);
        string base64 = padded.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+");
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using .net6. I simply included `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` as dependency. (This dependency works in .net framework as well as in higher .Net versions)

and decrypted JWT token as below:

```
// replacing Bearer from jwtToken with empty string.
// here jwtToken will be the value as "Bearer <<token>>"
string tokenValue = jwtToken.Replace("Bearer", "");

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenValue);
```

Now the `token` you got have all the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string getRoleFromJwt()
    {
        string jwtEncoded = Request.Headers.Authorization;
        jwtEncoded = jwtEncoded.Replace("Bearer ", "");
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtDecoded = handler.ReadToken(jwtEncoded) as JwtSecurityToken;
        var claim = jwtDecoded.Claims.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Type.EndsWith("/role"));
        if (claim == null)
            return "";
        return claim.Value;
    }
```

Comment: This is SolarBear's solution with a little modification. This assumes that you want to retrieve ClaimType.Role value. SolarBear's solution didn't work for me because Claim.Type contains more data than just the word "role" but it ends with "/role". See my modification below : var claim = jwtDecoded.Claims.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Type.EndsWith("/role"));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why not use `handler.ReadJwtToken(...)` and avoid casting `as JwtSecurityToken`?

Answer (score 1):

with [jose-jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jose-jwt/) nuget package it can be done by the following call:

```cs
var decodedToken = Jose.JWT.Payload(encodedToken);
```

It will decode token in the same way as it is done e.g. on jwt.io.