# ihttpcontextaccessor.httpcontext.user.findfirst(claimtypes.nameidentifier).value is null

Tags: httpcontext, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I have a service like this:

```
public class CurentUserService : ICurentUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public string UserId { get; set; }


    public  CurentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;





        this.UserId = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);


    }
```

and I add to startup

```
      services.AddScoped<ICurentUserService, CurentUserService>();

        //services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

but when à used via dependency injection is all time null when I was logged.

I use asp.net core version 3.1.0

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What sort of authentication system are you using? If you are using a JWT you need to specify that like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112258/how-do-i-get-current-user-in-net-core-web-api-from-jwt-token

Answer (score 0):

Can't explain why but this code works

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {

        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        
    }
public string UserId => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

In startup

```
services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

source: [github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/issues/119](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/issues/119)

Comment: Does this code work? This isn't working on my end!

Comment: my startup.cs 
services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

Comment: if you had used the code mentioned in that GitHub repo, then you need to change the code slightly like in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079005/3811265

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what works for me was injecting the interface of the **HttpContextAccessor**
`(IHttpContextAccessor)` inside my DI container and registering `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`