# Writing Tests for .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, testing

I am very new to .NET / C#.

I am using jwt for means of authentication. I have this object:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
  issuer: "example.com",
  audience: "example.com",
  claims: claims,
  expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(TOKEN_EXPIRY_DAYS),
  signingCredentials: creds
);
```

However, I manually add a "created" property:

```
token.Payload["created"] = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

All I need to do is to write a test that checks to see if the token object has an attribute called "created".

I have tried something like this:

```
tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(
  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
);
Assert.NotEmpty(tokenResponse.token["created"]);
```

But this fails. Any ideas?

Comment: This might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340078/how-to-decode-jwt-token

Comment: Why does this fail? What is the assertation result (exception) that occurs when you Assert.NotEmpty?

Comment: thanks @Blast_dan. That was super helpful! I did not come across that before.