# C# .net Core read JWT rs256 payload

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, rsa

it's simple to read payload if JWT token with hash algorithms(hs256 f.e.):

```
string Payload = JwtCore.JsonWebToken.DecodeToObject(token, secretKey) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

But jwtCore use only with hash algorithms, how to be with rs algorithms?

Now I have token on RS256 and also have Public key

On server I need only send token to another server for validate and to read data from payload

On site [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) I've just put my token with no public key and there is show me payload, how ca I do it on c# .net Core?

Comment: You can read the token using `JwtSecuirtyTokenHandler`.

Comment: When you can read your token on jwt.io, it's probably a "normal" signed JWT (aka JWS). In this case, the algorithm is only relevant if you want to **verify** the token. **Decoding** the payload is not influenced by the signing algorithm, the payload is just a base64url encoded JSON. Or are you talking about encryted tokens (JWE)?

Comment: @user1672994 Pls send some link with tutorial - how to read payload jwt token with rs256

Comment: @jps token readed normal on jwt.io without keys. It's probable mean that token isn't ecrypted. I don't need to validate token, just read some data from payload

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks I found solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340078/how-to-decode-jwt-token