# Azure Functions: Use the user in Cosmos DB binding

Tags: authorization, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've created azure functions with CosmosDB binding. These functions are authorized - they expect to receive the user JWT bearer from the Authorization header.

How can I use the user info in my queries to get resources based on the authorization. For example, get all the items in the partition `{user.oid}-todos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://blog.spectologic.com/2018/03/15/cosmos-db-access-control-with-users-permissions/) post offers a detailed description and even an [example](https://spectologic.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/cosmosdb-security-lab.zip) how to handle users and permissions in CosmosDB.

Alternatively, if you just want to get the *oid* from the received token and use this as the partition key, I'd go for an approach as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340078/how-to-decode-jwt-token) and then just create queries based on the value.

Setup (Nuget) for Azure Functions v3, .NET Core 3.1:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.7" />
```

```cs
    [FunctionName("CosmosDBAccess")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]DocumentClient client,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Get oid from your token 
            var token = string.Empty;
            var hasToken = req.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var tokenHeader);
            if (hasToken)
            {
                // Assuming token is in header as "Bearer <token>"
                token = tokenHeader[0].Split(" ")[1];
            }
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var jti = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "oid").Value;

            // Create query
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db", "collection");
            using (var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(uri, 
                new FeedOptions() { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(jti) })
                .AsDocumentQuery())
            {
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    // Get results
                    FeedResponse<Document> recordSet = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>();
                }
            }

            // more stuff
```

This returns all documents where the partition key equals the *oid* from the authorized calling user.

// Edit: Here I've added a sample for JS. However, I don't have any clue how to get the oid from the token. If you manage to obtain it, I think this might work. Please excuse my "bad practice" when it comes to JS, I don't use that at all.

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    
    const { CosmosClient } = require("@azure/cosmos");
    const endpoint = "<your-cosmosdb-connection>";
    const key = "<your-key>"
    const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });

    var results = []

    async function main() {
        // Get oid
        var oid = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
        console.log(oid)

        // Get Database 
        const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: "db" });
        console.log(database.id);
        
        // Get Collection
        const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: "collection" });
        console.log(container.id);

        // Query items
        const { resources } = await container.items
            .query("SELECT * from c", { partitionKey: oid })
            .fetchAll();
        
        for (var r of resources)
        {
            results.push(r)
            console.log(r.id)
        }
    }

    main().catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    await main()

    // Return response
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: results
    };
}
```

Comment: Ho, I'm sorry that I didn't mentioned earlier. I need it in JavaScript / TypeScript

Comment: There are no such annotations in JavaScript / TypeScript. What is the alternatives in these platforms?

Comment: At first you should get the CosmosClient:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/cosmos-readme?view=azure-node-latest#install-this-package

Unfortunately neither I know how to get the _oid_ in js nor how to add the partitionkey feed option. 

Maybe you can find something in the docs: 
General: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/cosmos-readme?view=azure-node-latest
Partition key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/partitionkey?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: @nrofis I've added a sample to my answer above. As mentioned, I don't know how to obtain the oid from a Bearer token.

Comment: Thanks! I have the code that get the `oid`. Actually, if Azure Functions will support this as part of the binding mechanism it will be awesome! Even though this code works, binding is much shorter and simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you have the _oid_ already, you might use the real js binding:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=javascript#queue-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-sqlquery-1
where you can also use the `partitionKey` property in the function.json and access the results via:
`var documents = context.bindings.documents;`

Comment: I mean, I extract the oid from the Authorization header. It requires few basic JS commands, so I don't know if I can use the binding directly