# How to validate jwt token in web api action method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an URL to generate jwt token for API calls. I want to create a web api action method with token autherizion. How can I validate the token inside the action method?

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/customer")]
    public String customer(APICustomer APICustomer1)
    {
try
    {
    insert_Customer(APICustomer1.custid,APICustomer1.custname,APICustmer1.status);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {} 
    return APICustomer1.custid+": is Inserted";
    }
```

Comment: Hi, jwt token is already validated by [Authorize] tag. It works if you set all correctly

Comment: How could I get user name from the token?

Comment: You should use ClaimsIdentity read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340078/how-to-decode-jwt-token

Comment: Assuming that you have included a claim for the userName with type "ClaimTypes.Name" you can access it inside your controller from the HttpContext:
 httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;