# How can i get the user name after login using Oauth2 with Graph Api?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am connecting to Microsoft Api. I authenticate using c# and getting the access token, but is cant seem to get the username that authenticated .
These are the fields returned  token_type, expires_in, access_token,  refresh_token, scope

I make a call to MS Graph using the following:

```
<authUri>?response_type=code&client_id={ClientId}&scope={Scope}&redirect_uri=
<MyRedirectUrl>
```

Is there a field i can get which can be decoded to get the user name that logged in via the Microsoft screen to authenticate ?

Comment: Usually you would get that info from the claims in the token itself.

Comment: if you decode the `access token`, there normally is a `sub` attribute which stands for `subject`. This is the identified for the user that authenticated.

Comment: when you mention "decode the token" how can i decode the token ? Is there a standard Microsft routin i can use ?

Comment: if you don't want to use a standard MICROSOFT routin to get the username of the signed in user, you can just [decode the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340078/how-to-decode-jwt-token) manually. But if you want to use the standard routin, pls show us how you add the authentication so that we may find a suitable solution

Comment: @Ting Wang  works perfect.