# Jwt Role authentication in controller ASP.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I am writing a cooperative web API with asp.net core 2.1 using postgresql as db. after the user sign in user is given a JWT token that will be use for the front end side authentication (Front end will be implemented with angular 2+). I want to store the user role in JWT and when the user sign In, user role will be read from the db and it will be store (authorize Role) So I will write Roles on the controller method. I want to use the Authorize attribute.

```
   // Auth Controller
    [HttpGet("GetUsers")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        var users = _authRepository.GetUsers();
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

and Repository.cs

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
{
    var users = _context.Users.ToList();
    return users;
}
```

***Question:*** Do I need to write a middleware to read each user role from JWT and a put that role to the Identity Principal Claims? Please share your experince. I will be glad to know your approch.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here... What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I want to manage user role based on JWT token. Do I need a middleware for that.

Comment: If you use the Microsoft ASPNET Core Jwt library/handlers  (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) then any Roles claims in the incoming validated JWT will automatically be extracted and populated in the ClaimsPrincipal (?) and available to use with the Authorize(Roles="...")] attribute.

Comment: I did the same and it worked for me thank you I read from the JWT document. Identity Priciples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad I solved this question I am sharing the complete middleware. In every request by the user the middleware will check the userRole that is embadded in JWT token middle point `xxxx.UserInformation.yyyyy` we will take that user information.

```
public class AuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    // Dependency Injection
    public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Read the Header
        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        // If header is not null
        if (authHeader != null)
        {   //Fixing the start point and end point           
            int startPoint = authHeader.IndexOf(".") + 1;               
            int endPoint = authHeader.LastIndexOf(".");

            var tokenString = authHeader.Substring(startPoint, endPoint - startPoint).Split(".");
            var token = tokenString[0].ToString()+"==";

            var credentialString = Encoding.UTF8
                .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(token));

            // Splitting the data from Jwt
            var credentials = credentialString.Split(new char[] { ':',',' });

            // Trim this string.
            var userRule = credentials[5].Replace("\"", ""); 
            var userName = credentials[3].Replace("\"", "");

             // Identity Principal
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("name", userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRule),
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "basic");
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        } //will move to the next middlware
        await _next(context);
    }


}
```

Now we need to call this middleware when the application start by goint to Startup.cs

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Authorization Middleware
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
     //   Other Middleware will come here

        app.UseMvc();


    }
}
```

Now Go to controller and Put an attribute on Methods.If the Role is admin it will execute the method or else it will return 403 Status Code.

```
[HttpGet("GetUsers")]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        var users = _authRepository.GetUsers();
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

I wish this helped for everyone who will Work with Authentication and Authorization using JWT Authentication in asp.net core all versions.

Comment: even you can add two values in roles.