# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Jwt setting custom claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

I have this code that is supposed to set claims for a user. It works fine when I use identity and the default login. However, when I use jwt as authentication in another application, I don't have ApplicationUser as my ApplicationUser is stored in the other application that authenticates the user. How can I customize this code so that it works with jwt?

```
private readonly SignInManager<TIdentityUser> _signInManager;

public CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper(SignInManager<TIdentityUser> signInManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}

public async Task SignInUserAsync(TIdentityUser user, bool isPersistent, IEnumerable<Claim> customClaims)
{
    var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var claims = (from c in claimsPrincipal.Claims select c).ToList();
    var savedClaims = claims;
    if (customClaims != null)
    {
        identity.AddClaims(customClaims);
    }
    await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
        claimsPrincipal,
        new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent });
}
```

I guess my main intention is to set my users claims in the httpcontext and not in a cookie and I want to do that without using identity.

EDIT:

My application structure

AuthenticationApp (server)

- Responsible for authenticating users
- Generates and Decodes Jwt
- Checks if the user has the appropriate roles and returns true/false via rest api

MainApp (client)

- Makes an api call to AuthenticationApp
- Does not use identity at all
- Sends Jwt everytime I need to check the role of the user

I understand that I will be able to decode the jwt client side. However, I do not know where I can store the decoded jwt details so that I can use it in the view. My initial idea was to use Httpcontext like normal applications that user Identity. However, I am stuck with the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Jwt implement signinmanager claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256440/asp-net-core-jwt-implement-signinmanager-claims)

Comment: It’s different. I’m trying to see if there’s an alternate way to set httpcontext items

Answer (score 1):

For sharing the Identity information between Controller and View, you could sign the User information by `HttpContext.SignInAsync`.

Try steps below to achieve your requirement:

- Controller Action

  ```
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
  {
      var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "edward"));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "edward zhou"));
      //add your own claims from jwt token
      var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
      await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });            
      return View();
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  @foreach (var item in Context.User.Claims)
  {
     <p>@item.Value</p> 
  };
  ```
- To make above code work, register Authentication in `Startup.cs`

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
      Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {   
       //your rest code     


       services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      //your rest code
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
  }
  ```

  }